# How to find winform application in visual studio 2022?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2022, tic-tac-toe

In my visual studio 2022 when I am tryting to build up a tic tac toe game, i need a winform application but i am unable to find it on my visuals studio 2022. can some one please tell me how to find winform application for C# in vs2022? thanks in advance!

I tried by creating new project to see if there's any winform application but I failed.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2022, you could create a Windows Forms Application project by following these steps：

1. Open Visual Studio 2022.
2. Go to the "File" menu.
3. Select "New" and then "Project...".
4. In the "Create a new project" window, you can search for "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)" or "Windows Forms App (.NET)" in the search box at the top right corner.
5. Select the appropriate template depending on whether you want to use the .NET Framework or .NET (Core/.NET 5+) for your project.
6. Choose a name and location for your project, and then click "Create".
   Once your project is created, you will have a Windows Forms Application project template.

If you are still unable to find the Windows Forms Application project template, it's possible that you might not have installed the necessary workload or components during the Visual Studio installation. In that case, you can modify your Visual Studio installation to include the workload for desktop development, which includes Windows Forms, WPF, and other desktop application development tools.

1. Open the Visual Studio Installer.
2. Click on "Modify" for your Visual Studio installation.
3. Under the "Desktop & Mobile" tab, make sure to check the "Desktop development with .NET" workload.

[image]

4. Click on the "Modify" button to install the selected workload.
   After modifying your Visual Studio installation and installing the necessary workload, you should be able to create a Windows Forms Application project without any issues.